# How do I display currency with two 0's in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to display the total price from my TipCalculator as `$147.00`, but it is only returning a single 0 at the end `$147.0`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Instead of $147.0 what is the result you're looking for?

Comment: You're going to have to include the code you're using to get your result. Otherwise we're all just guessing. Also your title doesn't seem to match your problem, so maybe [edit] your post and provide some clarity.

Comment: I think I got it. I had to use a `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` to get it right. My bad, and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for [`DecimalFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/text/DecimalFormat).

It can be used to format a number with fixed decimals, for example

```
val num = 147
val df = DecimalFormat("#.00")

println(df.format(num)) //prints 147.00
```